# Влияние форматирования кода на вёрстку

Tags: html, вёрстка

Приветствую, Хэшкодовцы.

У меня возникли странные проблемы с вёрсткой.

Задача: задать расстояние между элементами "текст 1", "текст 2" и "текст 3" в 1px.

На скриншоте показаны 2 элемента с классом "widget-toggle".
[image]

Разметка первого элемента с точки зрения читабельности кода, выполнена хорошо, а разметка второго не очень.. Но почему-то именно из-за этой разметки изменяется расстояние между элементами "текст 1", "текст 2" и "текст 3", хотя в коде чётко прописано:

```
margin-left: 1px;
margin-right: 1px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
```

Подскажите, как у первого элемента с классом "widget-toggle" задать нужное расстояние между элементами "текст 1", "текст 2" и "текст 3" не изменяя разметку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добрый день! Данное поведение специфично для inline-элементов, могу посоветовать следующее:

```
    <div class="widget-toggle">
              <span>Текст1</span><!--
            --><span>Текст2</span><!--
            --><span>Текст3</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Думаю, этот вариант больше всего подойдёт)

Answer (score 3):

Перенос строки в html влияет на отображения как пробел, ну или приблизительно.
Так что если вы делаете перенос строки между элементами, то возникает расстояние.
Таким образом данную проблему решать либо добавлением удалением переносов(что лучше всего), либо дикими костылями, например убивая `font-size` до нуля в `div`, но устанавливать его в нормальное значение во вложенных `span` (имхо это ужасно)
Другие варианты в голову не приходят

Comment: Костылями пользоваться не очень хочется.. Но неужели нет другого способа? Ведь строчка:
<span>текст 1</span>
Может распухнуть до:
<span class="..." id="..." onclick="function_name()" another_attribute="...">текст 1</span>
Что, мягко говоря, не очень читабельно.

Comment: ни кто не мешает использовать перенос внутри тега(в вашем случае `span`), тогда дыры не будет

Comment: Но ведь так будет не совсем эстетично))

Comment: Но тем не менее, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Можно после загрузки пробежаться через JS по `DOM` и удалить текстовые дочерние узлы у `div`...

Comment: Можно. Только вот для чего?